# extract 1st image tag from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to know how to extract 1st image URL from a mysql Query.

For a example:

```
<p>Nowadays forums have become very popular, almost every site on the 
web have a forum. An Internet forum, bulletin board or message board, is
 an online discussion site where people can hold conversations in the 
form of posted messages.</p>
<p>This is a list of top 10 free and open source software for creating your own forum.</p>
<h3>1. phpBB</h3>
phpBB is a free flat-forum bulletin board software solution that can 
be used to stay in touch with a group of people or can power your entire
 website.<br><br><img alt="" src="http://www.yoursite.com/phpbb.jpg" align="none"><br><br><h3>2. Simple Machines Forum</h3>
SMF is a free, professional grade software package that allows you to set up your own online community within minutes.<br><br><img alt="" src="http://www.yoursite.com/smf.jpg" align="none"><br>
```

From this i need to extract http://www.yoursite.com/phpbb.jpg

How can i do this. Thank in advance

Comment: I would fetch the data and parse in php

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/dom

Comment: I think you should go to tutorials first, and learn a little bit of MYsql, PHP and Mysql (at least)

Comment: There is no point in parsing texts using mysql query. Databases are intended to store data, not parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = '
<p>Nowadays forums have become very popular, almost every site on the 
web have a forum. An Internet forum, bulletin board or message board, is
 an online discussion site where people can hold conversations in the 
form of posted messages.</p>
<p>This is a list of top 10 free and open source software for creating your own forum.</p>
<h3>1. phpBB</h3>
phpBB is a free flat-forum bulletin board software solution that can 
be used to stay in touch with a group of people or can power your entire
 website.<br><br><img alt="" src="http://www.yoursite.com/phpbb.jpg" align="none"><br><br><h3>2. Simple Machines Forum</h3>
SMF is a free, professional grade software package that allows you to set up your own online community within minutes.<br><br><img alt="" src="http://www.yoursite.com/smf.jpg" align="none"><br>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$images = $xpath->query("//img");
$first_image = $images->item(0);
$firstsrc = $first_image->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue;
echo $firstsrc;
```

OUTPUT:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/phpbb.jpg
```

---

UPDATE: another short answer by @uınbɐɥs:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($text);
$firstsrc = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
echo $firstsrc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Simple HTML dom parser library.
Its simple and easy

```
$html = str_get_html('Your HTML string here');

// Find all images 
$image = $html->find('img',0);
```

This will give you the first image tag